# Расчет показателя из двух DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо посчитать сумму потраченную каждым пользователем по месяцам за каждый вид услуг (сообщения и звонки) и суммарное количество средств, потраченных за месяц) информация по лимитам, которые входят в тариф представлена в df1, информация о самих пользователях в df2. 
Если количество сообщений или трафика больше чем входит в тариф, то считаем сколько за это заплатил пользователь, если не превысил лимит, то считаем что стоимость 0.

```
df1 = [[50, 4000, 3, 5, tarif1], [1000, 2000, 2, 4, tarif2]]
columns = ['messages_included', 'minutes_included','rub_per_message', 'rub_per_minute', 'tariff_name']
df2 = [[1, tarif1, 5, 20, 100], [1, tarif1, 6, 150, 250], [1, tarif1, 7, 100, 200], [2, tarif1, 5, 45, 10], [2, tarif1, 6, 100, 0], [3, tarif2, 5, 12, 98], [3, tarif2, 6, 10, 6000], [3, tarif2, 7, 800, 2000], [4, tarif2, 5, 80, 10], [4, tarif2, 6, 1000, 500]   
columns = ['user_id', 'tariff', 'month', 'total_messages', 'calls_sum']
```

Предполагаемый результат, в df2 добавятся колонки, стоимость затраты за месяц на звонки и сообщения, и колонка с суммарными затратами сверх тарифа складывающаяся из стоимости сообщения и звонков.

```
columns = ['user_id', 'tariff', 'month', 'total_messages', 'calls_sum', 'messages_revenue', 'calls_revenue', 'total_revenue']
```

Итоговая таблица должна выглядеть вот так https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHOpM.jpg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете привести в вопросе таблицу-результат, которую вы хотите получить?

Comment: @MaxU добавил колонки таблицы

Comment: вы можете добавить __данные__ результирующей таблицы? Лучше всего привести аналог вывода `print(result_df)`...

Comment: @MaxU результат должен оказаться в df2 в дополнительных колонках

Comment: это как раз понятно! Для проверки полученного результата хотелось бы увидеть __значения__ столбцов: 'messages_revenue', 'calls_revenue', 'total_revenue' в `df2`

Comment: @MaxU в этом проблема, их нужно посчитать в соответствии с условием, т.е из количества сообщений вычесть лимит сообщений установленный в df2. Если он превышает то умножить оставшиеся на стоимость тарифа. Простите, может я не правильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вы можете взять ваш `df2` из вопроса и посчитать вручную три "revenue" столбца и представить в вопросе результат - это позволит отвечающим на вопрос убедиться, что вопрос был правильно понят и сверить результат...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU добавил картинку как должно выглядеть в итоге

Comment: @Anofelesoff Вы не внимательно ознакомились с рекомендациями по ссылке выше, там есть такое:  **Как делать не надо**: _приводить пример данных, код или вопрос в виде картинки_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
t = df2.reset_index().merge(df1.rename(columns={"tariff_name": "tariff"})).set_index("index")
t["messages_revenue"] = (t["total_messages"] - t["messages_included"]).clip(0) * t["rub_per_message"]
t["calls_revenue"] = (t["calls_sum"] - t["minutes_included"]).clip(0) * t["rub_per_minute"]
t["total_revenue"] = t["messages_revenue"] + t["calls_revenue"]
res = df2.join(t.filter(regex="revenue"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [69]: res
Out[69]:
   user_id  tariff  month  total_messages  calls_sum  messages_revenue  calls_revenue  total_revenue
0        1  tarif1      5              20        100                 0              0              0
1        1  tarif1      6             150        250               300              0            300
2        1  tarif1      7             100        200               150              0            150
3        2  tarif1      5              45         10                 0              0              0
4        2  tarif1      6             100          0               150              0            150
5        3  tarif2      5              12         98                 0              0              0
6        3  tarif2      6              10       6000                 0          16000          16000
7        3  tarif2      7             800       2000                 0              0              0
8        4  tarif2      5              80         10                 0              0              0
9        4  tarif2      6            1000        500                 0              0              0
```

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативное решение:

```
formulas = """
messages_revenue = (total_messages - messages_included) * rub_per_message
calls_revenue = (calls_sum - minutes_included) * rub_per_minute"""

t = (df2
     .reset_index()
     .merge(df1.rename(columns={"tariff_name": "tariff"}))
     .set_index("index"))

res = (df2
       .join(t.eval(formulas)
              .filter(regex="\_revenue")
              .clip(0)
              .eval("total_revenue = messages_revenue + calls_revenue")))
```

---

результат:

```
In [81]: res
Out[81]:
   user_id  tariff  month  total_messages  calls_sum  messages_revenue  calls_revenue  total_revenue
0        1  tarif1      5              20        100                 0              0              0
1        1  tarif1      6             150        250               300              0            300
2        1  tarif1      7             100        200               150              0            150
3        2  tarif1      5              45         10                 0              0              0
4        2  tarif1      6             100          0               150              0            150
5        3  tarif2      5              12         98                 0              0              0
6        3  tarif2      6              10       6000                 0          16000          16000
7        3  tarif2      7             800       2000                 0              0              0
8        4  tarif2      5              80         10                 0              0              0
9        4  tarif2      6            1000        500                 0              0              0
```